# How to convert an excel to a .csv file without using any packages in .nET C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv, upload

I will explain my problem from scratch

I have an upload button. when i choose an excel file and  click on the button the file gets uploaded on to my specific folder.
This is working.

Now I want to read the data from this excel sheet and store it in variables.
There is always specific no: of columns in my excel sheet.

I cannot install any third party packages for this nor I can use oledb  or interop or openxml...
I tried all that and these are causing ambiguity problem with my other parts of code.

So I decided to manually convert this.
But the problem is, my csv file is storing some bytecodes and not the excel data...

````
public void document_excel_OnFileUploaded_Staff(object sender, FileUploadedEventArgs e)
        {

```
            fu_documents_Staff.TargetFolder = "~/UploadedFiles";
            DataTable dt = obj_common.Get_File_Code("CustDoc");
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() != "")
            {
                string files_name = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() +      e.File.GetNameWithoutExtension().ToString() + e.File.GetExtension();
                string filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(fu_documents_Staff.TargetFolder), files_name);`
`



                // Save the uploaded file
                e.File.SaveAs(filePath);

                // Convert Excel to CSV
                string csvFilePath = ConvertExcelToCsv(filePath);

                // Read the data from CSV
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(csvFilePath))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(line);
                        string[] values = line.Split(',');

                        // Process the data as needed
                        foreach (string value in values)
                        {
                            string i = value;
                            Console.WriteLine(i);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                // Cleanup the CSV file
                File.Delete(csvFilePath);

                hdn_doc_name_Staff.Value = e.File.GetNameWithoutExtension().ToString() + e.File.GetExtension();
                hdn_doc_sav_Staff.Value = files_name;
                lab_doc_name_out_Staff.Text = hdn_doc_name_Staff.Value;
            }
        }
`

` private string ConvertExcelToCsv(string excelFilePath)
        {
            string csvFilePath = Path.ChangeExtension(excelFilePath, ".csv");
           
{
    // Rest of the code...
}

            using (FileStream excelStream = File.Open(excelFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                byte[] excelData = new byte[excelStream.Length];
                excelStream.Read(excelData, 0, (int)excelStream.Length);

                using (StreamWriter csvWriter = new StreamWriter(csvFilePath))
                {
                    bool inQuotes = false;
                    StringBuilder csvLine = new StringBuilder();

                    foreach (byte b in excelData)
                    {
                        char c = (char)b;

                        if (c == '"')
                        {
                            inQuotes = !inQuotes;
                        }
                        else if (c == '\t')
                        {
                            csvLine.Append(inQuotes ? c : ','); // Use a delimiter other than comma (e.g., '|') if needed
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            csvLine.Append(c);
                        }
                    }

                    csvWriter.WriteLine(csvLine.ToString());
                }
            }


            Console.WriteLine("Excel file converted to CSV successfully!");
            return csvFilePath;
        }
`
````

Comment: so you want to tell me you are reading an excel files bytes and claim to get meaningful data?

Comment: You know that an xlsx file has a structure. - http://officeopenxml.com/anatomyofOOXML-xlsx.php

Comment: You are correct, directly reading the bytes of an Excel file and treating them as text will not yield meaningful data....so how can i do this without the help of a library or packages

Comment: Sorry, but what is your issue than? If I understood you, you somehow managed to read the excel file with meaningful data (though I did question it, with the code you have shown) and the only "issue" you have is `...my csv file is storing some bytecodes and not the excel data...` - so it seems everything is working as expected just one tiny little problem. BUT now in the comments it sounds like you have nothing, and all the provided code is meaningless since the very first step "how to read an xlsx file, without 3rd part library?" is already non-existent